# solve functional equation: $[f(x)]^2-[f(y)]^2$=$f(x+y)f(x-y)$

Tags: functional-equations

i am trying to solve following problems and please guys help me
suppose that,there is given following equation
$[f(x)]^2-[f(y)]^2$=$f(x+y) \cdot f(x-y)$
there was said that,it requires  some knowledge of calculus,first of all i  factor this equation as
$(f(x)+f(y)) \cdot (f(x)-f(y))$=$f(x+y)\cdot f(x-y)$ so it means that

1.$f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$
2.$f(x)-f(y)=f(x-y)$
so it means that $f(x)=a \cdot x$  right yes?where does it requires calculus?range of x,y are  all real numbers

Comment: $f \ast f \neq |f|^2$

Comment: You could use "\cdot" instead of "$*$"

Comment: If two products are equal it doesn't mean the terms are equal. Your conclusions 1) and 2) are not right...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is called the sine functional equation; for a start you may check [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3612552). It mentions that $f(x)=kx$ satisfies the equation. Of course, we also have
$$
\sin^2(x)-\sin^2(y)=\sin(x+y)\cdot \sin(x-y).
$$

Comment: Thanks for the link!